# Memory allocation of variables

Tags: c++, c, variables

I'm in confusion. Does the allocation of automatic, static and global variables take place at compile time or run time?

The thing I know is that at compile time, the source code is translated to machine language.

When the compiler finds a statement like `int a;`, it writes the instruction. Do any extra things happen, like memory allocation, at compile time?

What happens when the .exe file will be executed?

Whether computer (OS) or compiler will allocate sufficient memory of holding an integer at runtime or compile time.

**Also it is said that the address of a global variable is a compile-time constant. What does it mean?**
Please help to solve each question, especially the last one.

Comment: A declaration like `int a;` does not directly correspond to a machine instruction.

Comment: that isn't part of my homework .Question arises in my mind why old learning clashes with new one.also I always Google it till i freak out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Static global variables are allocated memory resources either at compile-time or run-time.  This depends on whether the static variables are zero-initialized, or if they have initial constant values.  For instance, code like

```
//global variable with internal linkage
static int array[100];
```

won't take up any room in the executable ... in other words the compiler/linker will not allocate memory in the executable for that array since it doesn't contain anything.  It will leave a stub though that indicates when the executable is launched, memory must be allocated for the array.  Once you launch the executable, the OS sees the stub left by the linker, and allocates and zero-initializes the memory for the array (as well as other memory for the heap, etc.).  On the other-hand,

```
//global variable with internal linkage
static int array[100] = { 1, 2, 3};
```

will take up space in the executable since it is initialized with constant values at compile-time.  Thus the compiler will emit code in the `data` section of the assembly file it generates that allocates storage for the array.  The linker will then properly layout the data-section and code sections of all the assembly files that are being linked into the final executable.  When the OS loads the executable into memory, the memory for the array is already part of the executable's memory "foot-print".

Automatic variables, since they are allocated on the stack during the execution of code, are allocated at run-time.

> Also it is said that address of global variable is compile time constant.

That's a bit misleading ... in C you can't know the exact memory-address of any global variables until the linker has created the executable, and the OS has loaded the executable into memory.  The only way this could be done would be if you hand-assembled a file and created a flat-binary that was specifically loaded into a given address by the operating system, but modern operating systems don't let you do that.  Instead, the addresses of global variables are given place-holders by the linker so that they can be substituted with the correct values when the OS loads the executable at run-time. So while the memory address is "constant" in the sense that it won't change over time while the program is running, its actual value is not assigned at compile-time.

Comment: you only talk about global variable with internal linkage .what happen for global variables with external linkage

Comment: Same thing essentially ... internal and external linkage just determine the visibility of a memory location from another code-module.

Comment: you mean a type of constant placeholder(address will be constant when given by OS ) is given to global variables

Comment: NOTE: "Also it is said that address of global variable is compile time constant" This is not the case in C++

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of variable:

- stack variables are done at runtime (though their size is know at compile time, the stack memory is only reserved on function entry, which makes it runtime allocation). there is also a special caveat with this, `alloca` allocates from the stack at runtime, even though it seems like its dynamic heap memory.
- heap variables are allocated at runtime, generally via `new`/`malloc`, however, the storage of the pointers may still be on the stack.
- global and static variables are allocated in a few ways. initialed ones will be allocated in the binary by the compiler, with their initial value (or an initializer will be called at start up for objects). uninitialized data will be allocated via the OS loader by reading the PE, this is why data is split between various segments, such as `.rdata`, `.data` & `.bss`.

Now with the variables that are global/static, the compiler can bind a relative or prefered constant address for them, cause they are allocated within the binary.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler generates an object file (`.obj` under Windows, `.o` under
Unix) which contains more than just machine instructions, and not all
constructs in C++ will result in machine instructions.  When memory
allocation occurs is (formally, at least) unspecified.  In practice,
since the number of automatic and dynamic objects isn't known at compile
time (since functions may be recursive), they can only be allocated at
compile time, and the compiler will generate code to do this (although
it will typically allocate *all* of the automatic variables in a 
function with one or two instructions at the top of the function).  On
the other hand, the compiler knows exactly how many objects with static
lifetime will exist.  All of the implementations I'm familiar with
generate loader records in the object file which ultimately result in
the system loader allocating these as part of the initial process image
when loading the program; there is no code in the loaded program which
allocates them.  (If the initialization isn't static, there will be code
which initializes them.)

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of questions here. In C you have stack memory and heap memory. Globals are on the heap. All non malloc variables that are not global are on the stack. Think of stack memory as memory that you create inside of your functions. Every function call adds another layer to your stack. When the function returns, the non-malloc memory that was allocated inside that function is returned. A global variable's memory location never changes which is why it's position can be static at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

> When the compiler finds a statement like int a;, it writes the
>   instruction.Does any extra things happen like memory allocation at
>   compile time?

Yes, space is reserved for the variable on the stack.

> What happens when the .exe file will be executed?

Too long to be answered here. Narrow your question.

> Whether computer(os) or compiler will allocate sufficient memory of
>   holding an integer at runtime or compile time.

Depends on how you allocate the memory on your code.

> Also it is said that address of global variable is compile time
>   constant .what does it means??

This means the memory is reserved on compile time, thus the address of the global variable will not change during execution.

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler finds the `int a;` statement in a function, he writes something like `sub esp,sizeof(int)`, and when the program runs and get this line, it allocates memory.

If it's a global varibale, the compiler write a `resb` instruction, which tell the OS to allocate memory while loading the program.