# GCC outputs very large executable for Mersenne program

Tags: c, gcc, memory-management, primes

For program from http://bellard.org/mersenne.html GCC produces ~130MB executable. Why?

Comment: This array t[1<<25] takes up about 129 MB of memory, i think.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try changing `t[1<<25]={2}` to `t[1<<25]` and the size of the *executable** will drop down to **7.3 K**. (Needless to say, you won't get the right results)

If it was just `t[1<<25]`, it wouldn't have taken any space at all.

The catch here is that the array is being initialized (first element=2, the next 2^25-1 elements all 0), and the global array gets placed in the data segment **only** because it is initialized.

---

Generating the assembly for the 2 versions and examining the difference makes it even more clear:

```
[axiom@axiom ~]$ diff without_mem.s with_mem.s 
15c15,21
<   .comm   t,134217728,32
---
>   .globl  t
>   .align 32
>   .type   t, @object
>   .size   t, 134217728
> t:                                ***<- HERE!***
>   .long   2                
>   .zero   134217724
```

As we can notice, in the original version, the assembler is directed to generate 2^27 (134217728 ) bytes in the data segment. So it becomes a part of the object file itself. ( *You can generate assembly by compiling with `-S` switch       `gcc -S -fverbose-asm t1.c`*)

---

But why 129 MBs?

```
   1<< n= 2^n (1 left shifted n times). 
 =>  1<<25=2^25. 
     now 1 Integer= 4 bytes =2^2 bytes 
 => 2^25 Integers=2^27 bytes=2^7 * 1 M bytes= 128 MBs
```

---

For more details, see :

- [Related
  Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197063/memory-allocation-of-variables).
- [Wiki page on data
  segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment)
- [Reading ia32 Assembly](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs164/fa11/ia32-refs/ia32-chapter-two.pdf)

---

*Note 1: It is an [object file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) in strict terms.

Note 2: As pointed out in the comments, It may also be noted that the total size of the process (program in execution) will be 129Mb even if the executable is of 7.3K. (The memory will be allocated once the program starts executing). You can see the memory usage of your program by using the `top` command.

Note 3: It is worth emphasizing that this holds only because t is global. Allocation for data local to a function still happens at runtime on the stack. So if `t` was local, the object file would've taken 7.3K only.

Note 4: Initialized `static` local variables, like initialized globals, are also kept in the `data` segment. A `static` global is *same* as a global except that you are limiting the scope of the variable to the current file only.

Comment: Even if the executable size is 7.3K the process size will still be 130 MB.

Comment: @brianbeuning It is quite obvious, but still added for completeness.

Comment: This is stunning, I've been brace-initializing arrays of considerable size _many_ times with GCC and never seen such a thing. Only non-uniform data is placed in the executable, everything else is initialized with a `memset` like loop. Maybe it's some odd optimization or debug flags being used?

Comment: @Damon It sure is. But turns out the data segment is indeed filled with **global** data that's initialized. I compiled without any optimization and debug flags ( debug symbols take up 1.4 K for this program anyways). For data local to a function, allocation happens at runtime (on the stack), so if this was a local array, the size would've been 7.3K only. Once loaded, the process would take up 129Mb, so this only becomes a problem if we were to deal with a situation where  secondary memory is less than main memory .

Comment: In a more or less empty project (no MT code, just the array declaration and a `for` loop that prints the elements) I get 129MiB when I make the array `static`. Otherwise, it's 7kiB. (Using `-O2` as standard, if that matters)

Comment: @Damon Initialized `static` variables, like globals, also find their place in the data segment (the `asm` generated clearly shows their allocation after the `.data` directive). Uninitialized static variables (all 0s) are kept in BSS. So i guess that explains it if my understanding is correct.

Comment: @axiom: Well, yes and no... uninitialized variables (whatever they are) don't take up any space anyway, ever. But what I'm seeing here is that _initialized_ arrays (such as `= {2}` or `= {}`) do not take up any more space than absolutely necessary. Except when you make the array `static`, then it takes up space for every single element, even if they're all zero... no idea why. I've not checked the `.S` file, but looking at the size of the executable is telling enough (hundreds of MiB vs some kiB).

Comment: @Damon This is getting interesting. If the `static` array is initialized as `{}`, it won't be placed in the data segment, but if I make it `{2}`, it does takes up the space. Sure the compiler is generating smarter assembly here,in some sense. Have a look http://pastebin.com/Mi54xgtS . So it is not taking space for every element if it is all 0! 
 And Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Damon The same holds for globals as well, if they are all zeros, initialized with a `{}`, they won't take any space at all. They are declared following the  `.bss` (!) directive so they will be allocated memory when the program loads.

Comment: You can make the object file and executable much smaller *and* get the correct output by dropping the initializer for `a` and adding an assignment `a[0]=2;` at the beginning of `main`. See https://gist.github.com/4288661

Comment: @KeithThompson Yeah. Another possibility would be to just pass the pointers around and declare the array inside `main()`.

Comment: @axiom: That would (in most implementations) put that *huge* array on the stack. Many systems allocate less space for stack than for static data.